# No puedo enviar ni redirigir en php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema para enviar un email con php y html ya que cuando pulso submit en el formulario de html me dirige a *enviar.php* en vez de a *gracias.html* y no envía el correo.

Este es todo el código:

index.html

```html
<form method='POST' action='enviar.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-groupUno">
  <input type="text" class="control" name='telefono' id="telefono" required placeholder="Introduce tu teléfono">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Quiero que me llamen </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" required> Acepto la política de privacidad.
  </div>
</form>
```

enviar.php

```php
<?php 
$destino = "aitor.ruiz@marketalia.com"
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

mail($destino, "contacto", $telefono);
header("Location:gracias.html");
?>
```

Comment: solo te falta el ``;`` al final de la linea ``$destino = "aitor.ruiz@marketalia.com"``, el resto esta correcto.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.